# MongoDB search in embedded array

Tags: java, mongodb, find

I am trying to store all my written java files in a MongoDB and so far I've applied a schema like this (incomplete entry):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52b861c230044fd08d6c27c4"),
"interfaces" : [
    {
        "methodInterfaces" : [
            {
                "name" : "add",
                "name_lc" : "add",
                "returnType" : "Integer",
                "returnType_lc" : "integer",
                "parameterTypes" : [
                    "Integer",
                    "Integer"
                ],
                "parameterTypes_lc" : [
                    "integer",
                    "integer"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "isValid",
                "name_lc" : "isvalid",
                "returnType" : "Boolean",
                "returnType_lc" : "boolean",
                "parameterTypes" : [
                    "Integer",
                    "Double"
                ],
                "parameterTypes_lc" : [
                    "integer",
                    "double"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "name" : "Calculator",
        "name_lc" : "calculator",
        "filename" : "Calculator.java",
        "filename_lc" : "calculator.java"
    }
],
"name" : "Calculator",
"name_lc" : "calculator",
"filename" : "Calculator",
"filename_lc" : "calculator",
"path" : "/xyz/Calculator.java",
"md5" : "6dec7e62c5e4f9060c7612c252cd741",
"lastModification" : ""
```

}

So far I am able to query a class that contains a method name, but I am not able to query a class with a certain name (let interfaces.name_lc="calculator") that *must* contain two methods with particular names (let's say "add" and "divide") which themselves should have two integer, resp. an integer and a double as parameters and both return an integer (don't question whether this is reasonable or not -- just for illustration purposes).

This is just one example; it can be more complex, of course.

I don't know how I can query for a particular class with method and specified parameters. I need to describe it sharp and want sharp results.

I am not able to construct a query, that would *only* return files like `Calculator ( add(integer,integer):integer; divide(integer,double):integer; )`. I get, e.g., `OtherClass ( add():void; method(integer):integer; )`, which is not what I want. I am trying this for days now, and maybe one can enlighten me, how to solve this in MongoDB. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do this in MongoDB with your document structure.  The issue I ran into is around the parameters - I'm assuming you care about the order of the parameters (i.e. `doSomething(String, int)` is not the same as `doSomething(int, String)`), and the query operators to check all the values in an array treat the array as a set, so a) order agnostic and b) eliminates duplicates (so `doSomething(String, String)` matches `doSomething(String)`) (this is because I was using the $all keyword, [see the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all), especially the note at the bottom).

I managed to get a large part of the query you wanted, however, which might point you in the right direction.

```
{ "$and" : [ //putting these in an "and" query means all parts have to match
    { "interfaces.methodInterfaces" : 
        { "$elemMatch" : { "name" : "add"}}           //this bit finds documents where the method name is "add"
    } ,
    { "interfaces.methodInterfaces" : 
        { "$elemMatch" : { "returnType" : "Integer"}} // This bit matches the return type
    } , 
    { "interfaces.methodInterfaces.parameterTypes" : 
        { "$all" : [ "Integer" , "Integer"]}          //This *should* find you all documents where the parameter types matches this array. But it doesn't, as it treats it as a set
    }
]}
```

If you're querying via the Java driver, this looks like:

```
BasicDBObject findMethodByName = new BasicDBObject("interfaces.methodInterfaces",
                                     new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("name", "add")));
BasicDBObject findMethodByReturn = new BasicDBObject("interfaces.methodInterfaces",
                                       new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("returnType", "Integer")));
BasicDBObject findMethodByParams = new BasicDBObject("interfaces.methodInterfaces.parameterTypes",
                                       new BasicDBObject("$all", asList("Integer", "Integer")));
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and", asList(findMethodByName, findMethodByReturn, findMethodByParams));
DBCursor found = collection.find(query);
```

I haven't included matching the class name, as this didn't seem to be the tricky part - just build up another simple query for that an add it into the "$and".

Since the arrays to store parameter types are not giving what you want, I suggest you think about something a little more structured, although it's a bit unwieldy.  Instead of

```
"parameterTypes" : [
    "Integer",
    "Integer"
]
```

Consider something like

```
"parameterTypes" : {
    "param1" : "Integer",
    "param2" : "Integer"
}
```

Then you won't be doing set operations, you can query each parameter individually.  This means you'll also get them in the correct order.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. It seems to be working the way you describe. I'll have to investigate some more.